# Event resource - returned by Google Calendar 'Get' method - not returning Attendees for events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I am trying to modify Manas Tungare's Google Calendar CRX Chrome Extension. The extension provides a quick overview of your Google Calendar on every tab.

[image]

I am trying to add Attendee names for each event in the view above. However, the Events Resource being returned  by the 'Get' method in the Google Calendar API does not seem to have the Attendees field for the events. The API page for the 'Get' method [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) indicates that an Event resource is returned, and the Event resource page [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) seems to indicate that Attendees field should be passed as a part of the resource.

I have linked the Github project below as well. The relevant code for this is in the [browser_action.js file](https://github.com/manastungare/google-calendar-crx/blob/master/src/browser_action.js)

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({method: 'events.feed.get'}, browseraction.showEventsFromFeed_);

browseraction.showEventsFromFeed_ = function(events) {
console.log(events);
}
```

Console log output for the events array (each event in the 'events' array returns the fields as given below)

---

**allday**: false

**description**: ""

**end**: 1613449800000

**event_id**: "<my_event_id>"

**feed**: {backgroundColor: "#9fe1e7", description: "", editable: true, foregroundColor: "#000000", id: "<my_email_id>", …}

**gcal_url**: "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=<my_event_id>"

**hangout_url**: "https://meet.google.com/<my_url>"

**reminders**: [{…}]

**responseStatus**: "needsAction"

**start**: 1613448000000

**title**: "<my_event_title>"

---

I am not sure why this is happening - could someone please help me understand why this is happening and how I can get the Attendee list? FYI, events are being created and attendees are being added within Google Calendar itself (non-programmatically). Aim is to programmatically retrieve the attendee list for use in the modified Google Chrome extension as described above.

**Other Links** -

- Google Chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-calendar/gmbgaklkmjakoegficnlkhebmhkjfich?hl=en
- Github page - https://github.com/manastungare/google-calendar-crx

Comment: The docs you've linked say "Service accounts need to use domain-wide delegation of authority to populate the attendee list." I'm not an expert on Google API though...

Comment: Interesting theory - I'll try to use the extension on my personal email id tomorrow (where hopefully this should not be an issue) and see if that changes anything. Thanks for spotting this - will update here in a day.

Comment: For some reason, I have not been able to get the extension working with personal email id easily. So I am not sure if that changes things yet. Will give this another go over the weekend. Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

`attendees` field should be defined in an [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) when you are creating it using [POST](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) (or with an [UPDATE](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)), but when you are using [GET](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) you don’t have to specify anything related to the attendees.

If an event resource doesn’t contain the Attendees field it means that they are not defined, you can check it using [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get?apix=true).

### update:

To populate the `attendees` field with a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) you need to use [Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation), as it's indicated in the [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource).

A snippet sample of code with Python to create a `Calendar service`:

```
key_path = 'serviceAccountKey.json'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"])
 
creds = cred.with_subject('onwerOfCalendar@something.com')
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

This way, you do not need to share the calendar with the service account, which you must do if you do not use `Domain-Wide Delegation`.

In order to activate it, you must first get the `client id` in [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and add the `scope` with the `client id` in [Google Admin](https://admin.google.com/Dashboard).